# How to make multiple objects in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I need to make multiple objects fall from the top.

I have tried to duplicate code but it did not work.

HERE is my code:

````
```var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: document.getElementById('myCanvas'), antialias: true});
      renderer.setClearColor(0x00ff00);
      renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff, 0);
      renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      // CAMERA!
      var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 3000);
      // SCENE!
      var scene = new THREE.Scene();
      // LIGHTS!
      var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5)
      scene.add(light);

      var light1 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.5)
      scene.add(light1);
      // TYPE OF 3D SHAPE!
      var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 100, 100, 20 );

      geometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationZ( Math.PI / 4 ) );
      geometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale( .6, 0.9, .6 ) );       // MATERIALs!
      var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xF3FFE2});
      var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      var mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      mesh.position.set(100, 500, -1000);
      mesh1.position.set(200, 500, -1000);

      scene.add(mesh);
      scene.add(mesh1);

      // RENDER LOOP
      color = '0x'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
      requestAnimationFrame(render);
      function render() {
        move = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);
        mesh.translateZ(-10)
        mesh.translateY(-10)
        if (move == 1){
        mesh.material.color.setHex(color);
        }
        mesh.rotation.x += 0.005; //MOVE SHAPE
        mesh.rotation.y += 0.1;
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
        scene.add(mesh)
      }```
````

I want to make many objects to fall from the sky. How can I do this with three.js because it did not appear?

I am a beginner to three.js so kindly help me! Note: not javascript beginner

Please Help Thanks in Advance! (i have been stuck on this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following live example is an enhanced version of your code. The basic idea is to use an array to manage individual objects in your scene:

```js
for ( var i = 0; i < count; i ++ ) {

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    scene.add(mesh);
    objects.push(mesh);

    // initial individual transformation

    mesh.position.set(- 1000 + Math.random() * 2000, 2000 * Math.random(), -1000 + Math.random() * 2000 );
    mesh.rotation.x += Math.PI * Math.random();
    mesh.rotation.y += Math.PI * Math.random();

}
```

You then use the same approach to update these objects in your animation loop.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/6bzfLag2/1/

However, be aware that this approach requires one draw call per object so it is not very performant for a large amount of objects. You should consider to use [InstancedMesh](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/objects/InstancedMesh) which was recently introduced in the engine. Study the following example to see how you can use it to transform individual objects but render them with a single draw call.

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_instancing_suzanne

`three.js R110`